# How to iterate over all Text Elements in a docx file with Python docx?

Tags: python

I got an Word document and want to iterate over all Text elements. The Strukture of the document is like:

```
Some text
   some other text
```

When i iterate over all Paragraphs i do only get "some text" but not "some other text"
my interatein loks like this:

```
for para in document.paragraphs:
print(para .text)
```

Comment: So you want to iterate line by line ?

Comment: you can use `with open('file_path', 'w') as file`

Answer (score 0):

i dident see the hole text because`document.paragraphs` does not show all text elements by design. In my word document was the missed text in an table so i hade to iterate throug the tables too